# Setup multiple login-modules in TeamCity 7

Tags: ldap, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I'm using TeamCity 7.1.1 for my Continuous Integration server.
For all of my colleagues and me I setup the jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.LDAPLoginModule which allows everyone to login with their windows account.

Some clients want to stay up to date with the build statusses so I wanted to create custom users (which do not have a Active Directory login) and give them the role of "project viewer". This can not be done somehow. I do not want to allow users to create their own account.

I googled for a solution but I can not find it.
I added a new login-module tag in the auth-type tag in main-config.xml but this didn't work either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: +1 from me as I want to do the same thing. I want an automated user without domain credentials to be able to download artefacts without using guest auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in the jetbrains issue tracker. See the response here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24268

Comment: Worth noting that this was closed down as a dup of http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-4524 - got my vote